# Calling an interface static method on an instance that implements it

Tags: c#

Given an object that implements an interface with a static method on it, how can I call that static method?

Note that I don't want to add `TRequest` to the generic signature, I am mimmicking IMediatR.

This is the error I am getting: `CS0176 Member 'IApiRequest<TResponse>.GetRequestPath()' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead`

```cs
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var request = new GetAdditionalUserClaimsQuery();
        Execute(request);
    }

    public static void Execute<TResponse>(IApiRequest<TResponse> request)
    {
        // How do I call GetRequestPath here?
        string requestPath = ((IApiRequest<TResponse>)request).GetRequestPath();
    }

    public interface IApiRequest<TResponse>
    {
        static abstract string GetRequestPath();
    }

    public class GetAdditionalUserClaimsQuery : IApiRequest<GetAdditionalUserClaimsResponse>
    {
        public static string GetRequestPath() => "accounts/get-additional-user-claims";
    }

    public class GetAdditionalUserClaimsResponse
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Think about it as a regular static method. How can you call a public static method on an instance? You can't...you have to fully qualify the static invocation (aka `GetAdditionalUserClaimsQuery.GetRequestPath();`. The same applies here.

Comment: Are you sure your `GetRequestPath` should be `static`? For me it seems more like something you call on `request` instance (as you currently try anyways) than on a class

Comment: I need to call it statically on the server to register API endpoints, and on instances in the client for determining where to call - so I need both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static methods don't need an instance so you can pass null.
Using reflection this works.

```cs
    public static void Execute<TResponse>(IApiRequest<TResponse> request)
    {
        var requestType = request.GetType();
        var method = requestType.GetMethod("GetRequestPath", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);
        var result = method?.Invoke(null, new object[] { });
    }
```

Comment: I had problems with doing this in WASM in the past, but I tried this morning and it works. Thank you!

Comment: You can also just pass null for the parameters instead of creating a new empty array. (Or Array.Empty<object>() if you really need to pass an array.)

Comment: I bet the Array.Empty avoids adding the object on the stack.  Good call

Answer (score 1):

Since multiple types could implement `IApiRequest<TResponse>`, you need to add another generic parameter, so that your method knows which type is implementing `IApiRequest<TResponse>` for this call;

```cs
public static void Execute<TRequest,TResponse>(TRequest request) where TRequest : IApiRequest<TResponse>{
    ... TRequest.GetRequestPath();
}
```

Note that this does allow the caller to make a mistake like;

```
public class AnotherType : GetAdditionalUserClaimsQuery{
   public static string GetRequestPath() => ... ;
}
Program.Execute<GetAdditionalUserClaimsQuery, GetAdditionalUserClaimsResponse>(new AnotherType());
```

You might want to add this extra parameter to your interface and seal your implementations;

```cs
public interface IApiRequest<TRequest, TResponse> where TRequest : IApiRequest<TRequest, TResponse> {}
public sealed class GetAdditionalUserClaimsQuery : IApiRequest<GetAdditionalUserClaimsQuery, GetAdditionalUserClaimsResponse> {}
```

Comment: I don't want to do that, because then I have to specify both generic types whenever I call the method, whereas at the moment it can infer it.  It's the same approach mediatr takes.